# Blackberry eclipse plugin

Tags: blackberry, plugins

How to set the BB plugin to eclipse? I have alreay installed the plugin 1.0 for o/s 6 and now
wants to add for the 4.3,4.5. Please help.

Comment: Please take a look at this link and set up the development environment.. http://www.9lessons.info/2011/07/get-started-developing-for-blackberry.html

Comment: you can download completed eclipse for blackberry here.http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/12002/Specify_AEP_settings_for_BB_app_proj_919731_11.jsp

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, go to Help-> Install new software:

In the 'Work with:' drop down, if you haven't already set it up, you will need to add a new Software Site called 'BlackBerry Java Plugin' (or whatever you like), but importantly the location should be set to http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.6/java (if you are, as you should be, using Eclipse 3.6.n, the latest version supported)

Eclipse will then check for available plugins, but they only go back as far as OS4.5, I believe prior to that you needed to use RIM's own JDE.